# Select from 2 Tables where Column's Value equals="blabla" in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am tryin' to make a code with 2 Tables. And I wanna see Age of users in both tables that equals to 25!

How can I do that in PostgreSQL or MySQL?

I've tried

```
SELECT tablef.age, tables.age 
FROM tablef 
INNER JOIN tables ON age=25;
```

Comment: Unclear..please add sample data and expected outcome , you may need UNION ALL rather than a join.

Comment: Not related to the question, but do not store age as a number , use date of birth then calculate the age

Comment: That join feels fishy: you'll get a cartesian product of all entries of both tables with age=25; perhaps it's what you want but... Your request will only yield a certain number of rows of the form `25  25`... Very informative

Comment: Is OPs goal not just trying to use a simple union instead of a join? Or am i misunderstanding the question? Like getting all objects from both tables with an age=25.. Something like "select id, age from tablef where age = 25 union all select id, age from tables where age = 25"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is at the join try using below query: -

```
SELECT tablef.age, tables.age
FROM tablef
INNER JOIN tables ON tablef.age = tables.age
WHERE tablef.age = 25;
```